# iOS push views based on text label text

Tags: ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have didSelectRowAtIndexPath selecting views based on the row number selected, i.e.:

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierFromStoryboard"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

}
```

But as I've now implemented a search bar I'd rather be selecting the views based on the cell.textLabel.text from the cell selected. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You can get the cell by using cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Click me"]) {
        DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierFromStoryboard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    }
    else if([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Click me instead"]){
        DetailViewController *detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IdentifierFromStoryboard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was hoping for a replacement for indexPath.row == 1 something along the lines of 'cell.textLabel.text' = @"Text from the label"' - your code just seems to be setting *cell but it doesn't help me choose which view gets pushed based on the cell's text label